# multi-select input fields in MarkLogic

Tags: xslt, xquery, marklogic

I have a multi-select input field in a form, in this case it's a set of checkboxes, but it could be a multi-select dropdown. 
The fields look fine in the form, but the request throws an error when the form is submitted. The query string is:

```
?headings=on&text=on&references=on&book-category[]=mis&book-category[]=bds&book-category[]=gts
```

PHP handles multi-select input fields as arrays. I thought xquery would treat them as sequences. Apparently, xquery cannot handle such a field in an http request. Has anyone succeeded at handling multi-select input fields in xquery?

Here is the xslt that generates the form field, which looks perfectly fine in the source code.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="r:body/sidebar/search:facet[@name='category']/search:facet-value">
    <xsl:variable name="category-display" select="text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="category-name" select="encode-for-uri(string-join(tokenize(lower-case(text()), ' '), ''))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="category-id" select="encode-for-uri(concat('adv_books_', string-join(tokenize(lower-case(text()), ' '), '')))"/>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="book-category[]" id="{$category-id}" value="{$category-name}" class="checkbox" />
    <label for="{$category-id}"><xsl:value-of select="$category-display" /></label>
    </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Here is the error from the log:

```
2015-03-26 21:16:54.017 Notice: 8040-MYSITE-HTTP: XDMP-QNAMELEXFORM: for $param in xdmp:get-request-field-names() -- Invalid lexical form for QName
```

I think xquery doesn't like the brackets in the parameter book-category[].

Comment: I don't see any XQuery here. Is it possible you're talking about an XPath problem (which is embedded in XSLT)?

Comment: No, the code I posted does not contain the xQuery that processes the HTTP request. I just posted that to illustrate there is nothing wrong with the actual input field on the form. It's the xQuery function that calls xdmp:get-request-field-names() that throws the error as seen in the log.

Comment: This has not much to do with XQuery, but with the XQuery processor you are using. Given that you mentionen a xdmp method I guess you are using MarkLogic. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic support HTTP parameters with multiple values, returning a sequence in XQuery for the value:

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-request-field

In MarkLogic 8, you can also use JavaScript:

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.getRequestField

It looks like the XSLT in the client is not creating the URL parameter correctly.  HTTP supports a multiple-value parameter by repeating the parameter for each value and not with a single parameter having an array for the value. The syntax for multiple-value parameters in HTTP is independent of the syntax of the server language used to access the values.

Hoping that helps.

Comment: I think you are right, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Comment: Did you try changing "book-category[]" to "book-category"?

Comment: It wouldn't be a multi-select set of checkboxes if I changed it to book-category without the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Had to enter this bit as an "answer" even though it isn't an answer as it's too long for a comment. The error is thrown in a file from the MVC framework that was used for this application, and I hesitate to make changes to the framework code:

```
declare function utils:get-request()
as element(req:request)
{
  element {fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/mvc/request","request")} {
    attribute method {fn:lower-case(xdmp:get-request-method())},
    attribute rewrite-url {xdmp:get-request-url()},
    attribute protocol {xdmp:get-request-protocol()},
    attribute client-ip {xdmp:get-request-client-address()},
    element req:status-code {200},
    element req:message {"OK"},
    element req:session {
      for $field in xdmp:get-session-field-names()
      return
        element {fn:concat("req:",fn:lower-case($field))} {
          xdmp:get-session-field($field)
        }
    },
    element req:params {
      for $param in xdmp:get-request-field-names()
      where fn:not(fn:exists(xdmp:get-request-field-content-type($param)))
      return
        element {fn:concat("req:",fn:lower-case($param))} {
          attribute content-type {xdmp:get-request-field-content-type($param)},
          for $value in xdmp:get-request-field($param) return element req:value {$value}
        }
    },
    (: SOME MORE CODE HERE :)
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried:

for $param in fn:distinct-values( xdmp:get-request-field-names() )

but it also threw the error.